# dynamic data undefined in generateMetaData

Tags: next.js, metadata, next.js13

I am using generateMetaData function to add metadata to my blog posts, data is fetched using graphQL. It works fine on my local machine but when deployed on vercel data becomes undefined, what could be wrong

below is my code:

`export async function generateMetadata({ params}: { params: { slug : string }}): Promise {
const post = await getPostBySlug(params.slug);

```
 return {
title: params.slug.split('-').join(' '),
 description: post.excerpt ||  'temporary description',
openGraph: {
   images: [ '/'+ post.coverImage?.url],
} }}`
```

this data fetching function fetches posts correctly on the page only issue is in the metadata function.

Comment: Are you using the same database in development and production?

Comment: yes I am using contentful CMS as data source

Comment: It's unclear with what's provided. I'd look at ensuring you authorization permissions are identical between both you dev and prod environments.